# Filter a list of datetimes by some interval (not range)

Tags: python, datetime, list-comprehension

This is kind of special case, I know. It's for a list of timestamps of photo captures that were taken by a program that did a poor job of taking the data at regular intervals.

Say I have these timestamps:

```
2012-01-11 10:53:19
2012-01-11 10:53:24
2012-01-11 10:53:29
2012-01-11 10:53:35
2012-01-11 10:53:40
2012-01-11 11:03:20
2012-01-11 11:03:25
2012-01-11 11:03:30
2012-01-11 11:13:20
2012-01-11 11:13:25
2012-01-11 11:13:30
2012-01-11 11:13:35
2012-01-11 11:23:19
2012-01-11 11:23:24
2012-01-11 11:23:30
2012-01-11 11:23:35
2012-01-11 11:23:44
2012-01-11 11:24:03
```

I'd like a list that is whittled down to datetimes that are at least 5 minutes apart from each other, and no others under that time. So for the example above, I'd like:

```
2012-01-11 10:53:19
2012-01-11 11:03:20
2012-01-11 11:13:20
2012-01-11 11:23:19
```

Comment: Good for you! What have you tried?

Comment: lol "Good for you!"? I'm not sure of the best way to do it. I've started looping through them keeping the last interval timestamp and compared the differences, but it seems kind of gross.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure of the best way to do it. I've started looping through them keeping the last interval timestamp and compared the differences, but it seems kind of gross.

That's pretty much the only way. A list comprehension is not much cleaner:

```
def select(v):
  threshold = 5
  if len(selected) > 0 and v < selected[-1] + threshold: 
    return False 
  selected.append(v) 
  return True

timestamps = [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12]
selected = []
print([x for x in timestamps if select(x)]) # 1, 6, 11
```

Notice it's not possible with just list comprehension as there's no way to know what was selected.

Comment: I thought there was a cleaner way, but I ended up doing something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use comparison betwen `datetime` object, for exemple:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> test_1 = datetime.strptime('2012-01-11 11:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S')
>>> test_2 = datetime.strptime('2012-01-11 11:10:00', '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S')
>>> date1 = datetime.strptime('2012-01-11 11:03:30', '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S')
>>> test_1 > date1
False
>>> test_2 > date1
True
```